# Export summary statistics to other format than Excel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, csv, statistics, arcgis-10.4

Is there a tool from the modelbuilder that is able to export a summary statistics table to .csv instead of .xls? 
As I need to standardize the solution in modelbuilder, so preferably via modelbuilder.

ArcMap 10.4.1 - Basic Version Concurrent use

Answer (score 5):

Use [Table To Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm) which says that it:

> Converts an input table to a dBASE or geodatabase table.

Name your output table *.csv, for example outtable.csv

Comment: Just to contribute to this answer, if you looked at the help panel when running this tool you would be forgiven if you thought it could not export to CSV. If you read the help page for this tool it does explicitly state it can write to a CSV format, which amazingly I never knew! Thanks @Björn!